# Send string to user prompt python

Tags: python, string, prompt

I'm trying to fix some database lookups.
I want to initiate a `ssh` session for the user with the `IP` that I've fetched from the code.

Is it possible to spawn a session or maybe send the string to user's prompt?
String would be similar to:

```
ip_port = '192.168.1.10 2004'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026536/looping-over-a-some-ips-from-a-file-in-python does this help?

Comment: Not really. This spawns ssh as a CLI module. But the point of my script is to spawn ssh for the user, like a login script.

Comment: If you want to implement your own REPL, you should check the [paramiko library](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko)